# How to find examples of periodic points of the (complex) exponential-function $z \to \exp(z)$?

Tags: exponential-function, fixed-point-theorems, tetration, fixed-points

***Background***: By considering the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837582)  which asks whether a certain summation-method $\mathfrak M$ for the (extremely divergent!) sum $\mathfrak M: S(z)=z + e^z + e^{e^z}+e^{e^{e^z}} + ...$ might be valid, I had the idea, that a good test for the validity of the summation-method would be to compare one result with cases, where the sum can be given on some standard way. 
For instance, if $z$ is a fixpoint $p$  of $\exp(z)$  having  $\exp(p)=p$ then $S(p) = p + p+ p+ p+...$ which could possibly been evaluated using the $\zeta(0)$ - definition.
But this is possibly no good test, a better one were, if for instance $p$ were a $2$- periodic point where the sign changes, (let's denote a fixpoint $p_1$ and a $2$-periodic point $p_2$) such that $\exp(p_2)=-p_2$ and the series becomes $S(p_2)=p_2 - p_2 + p_2 - ... + ...$ which can then be assumed to be the Cesarosum of the alternating series of a constant.

***First steps of my own approach***: This led to the idea to find such $2-periodic$ points to have example cases. 
What I've done so far was to screen segments of the complex plane , say a square around some $z_0$ of size $2x2$ in steps of $1/10$ and find local minima. Then take each local minima of the error ($|z_0 - e^{e^z}|$  as new center of a new square with $0.2 x 0.2$ size, and iterate this two or three times until the error is small enough and then use Newton-iteration to finally find a point $p_2$ (hopefully meeting the requirements for Cesaro-summability!).

This gave by tedious manual screening an initial set of $2$-periodic points. But all so far found $2$-periodic points were on the real-positive halfplane and so not suited for Cesaro-summation of $S(p_2)=p_2-p_2+p_2-...$ with alternating signs.

Here is a picture which included  a couple more points which I found by extrapolating linear trends in subsets of the found ones. See my initial answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3669767/1714)
[image: Picture]

### Question 1:

So my first question is now for ideas,
 - 1) how could I improve the search-routine? (Perhaps avoiding that manual screening at all)

The extrapolation-idea is very useful and allows to find *infinitely many* more $2$-periodic points completely automatically, but it still needs an initial manual screening to get at least $3$ points as germ for the extrapolation.

### Question 2:

The picture contain no pairs of $2$-periodic points having alternating signs on the real part.
I've tried to find analytically better solutions, of to even prove there are no such points, but arrived nowhere definite so far.
 - 2) Are there really no $2$-periodic points with negative real part?

### Question 3 & 4:

If there are indeed no such cases, what about $3$-periodic points or in general $n$-periodic points?
 - 3) Are there $n$-periodic points with negative real part?
 - 4) Is there any analytical method known how to find $n$-periodic points without manual screening? (For the finding of $1$-periodic (or "fix"-) points we have the Lambert W-function. For generalizing the Lambert W I had found a scheme giving power series, but which have extremely small range of convergence and I think are thus useless here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***update:*** an update on the Pari/GP routine, few textual improvements

I've got a sudden enlightenment which seems to solve the problem completely.

The key here is, that on one hand the fixed- and periodic points of $\exp(z)$ are ***all repelling*** *(this was also mentioned/proved in an article of Shen/Rempe-Gillen, pg 1, see reference below)*, and on the other hand the one single fixed point of $\log(z)$ is nicely attracting, but it is only a singular occurence.

### $1$-periodic points/fixed points

Well, further fixed points can be found by using branches of the $\log()$, say 
$$ \text{lb}(z,k) = \log(z) + k \cdot C \qquad \text{where } C = i 2 \pi$$
We may then have for some $p_1 = p_1' + C $ the equality 
$$ \exp(p_1) = p_1 = p_1' + C = \exp (p_1'+ C) $$
and on the other hand the inverse relation
$$ \text{lb} (p_1,1) = p_1'+ C = \text{lb}(p_1'+C,1)$$

Noticing this we can exploit the *attractive* property of the (iterated) logarithmizing to converge from some initial value to the desired fixpoint, say from $z=1+I$ to some $p_1$ .

Example:

```
z = 1+I     | %681 = 1 + I
z=lb(z,1)   | %682 = 0.34657359 + 7.0685835*I
z=lb(z,1)   | %683 = 1.9568606 + 7.8049907*I
z=lb(z,1)   | %684 = 2.0852451 + 7.6083262*I
z=lb(z,1)   | %685 = 2.0654578 + 7.5864764*I
```

From where we can now use the Newton-iteration to get even quadratic convergence rate and then find the arbitrary well approximated value of the desired fixed point $\exp(z)=z$

```
z=newton(z) | %686 = 2.0622777 + 7.5886312*I
exp(z)-z    | %687 = 6.6538205 E-211 - 1.9010916 E-211*I
```

Using the $k$'th multiple of the constant $C=i2\pi$ we can now find (and index) the (infinitely many) complex fixed points ($1$-periodic):
 $$ p_1 = \text{lb}(p_1,k) \to \exp(p_1)=p_1$$
Another example:

```
p_1 = 1+I         | %688 = 1 + I
p_1=lb(p_1,3)     | %689 = 0.34657359 + 19.634954*I
p_1=lb(p_1,3)     | %690 = 2.9774671 + 20.402703*I
p_1=lb(p_1,3)     | %691 = 3.0262041 + 20.275440*I
p_1= newton(p_1)  | %692 = 3.0202397 + 20.272458*I
exp(p_1)-p_1      | %693 = 1.6045424 E-219 + 0.E-220*I  \\ error is machine- epsilon
```

### 2-periodic points

That procedere for finding $1$-periodic points is of course well known. For the finding of $1$-periodic (or: fixed-) points we have also the LambertW-function and their branching behaviour for even an immediate solution. But none such function is known for the $n$-periodic points for $n\ge 2$. Thus we have to find our own procedure now...

For that search of $2$-periodic fixpoints I'll not go to explain the formulae in detail *(it is trivial but too tedious for this answer-box)*, but I simply state that for the search for a solution to
$$ \exp(\exp(p_2) ) = p_2 \ne \exp(p_2) $$
it suffices to use -instead of the iterated exponential-function- the iterated branched logarithm-function, where the branch-index is ***allowed/required to change between the two steps of iteration***:

$$ p_2 =  \text{lb}( \text{lb}(p_2,k_0),k_1) $$

Initialize arbitrarily, iterate and, if desired, refine using the Newton-iteration on the $\exp(\exp())$ function.
Example:

```
p_2 = 1+I                | %694 = 1 + I
p_2=lb(lb(p_2,-1),0)     | %695 = 1.7063287 - 1.5078409*I
p_2=lb(lb(p_2,-1),0)     | %696 = 1.9537456 - 1.4538908*I
p_2=lb(lb(p_2,-1),0)     | %697 = 1.9430376 - 1.4429267*I
p_2= newton(p_2)         | %698 = 1.9428329 - 1.4437804*I
exp(exp(p_2))-p_2        | %699 = 6.1238446 E-202 - 1.6330252 E-201*I
exp(p_2)-p_2             | %700 = -1.0588348 - 5.4784957*I
```

We have now:

```
 p_2            | %701 = 1.9428329 - 1.4437804*I
 exp(p_2)       | %702 = 0.88399815 - 6.9222761*I
 exp(exp(p_2))  | %703 = 1.9428329 - 1.4437804*I
```

which is indeed a $2$-periodic point.

It is meaningful now, to simplify the notation for finding $2$-periodic points. Just let us use a vectorial notation for the two branch-indexes and write
$$ p_2 = \text{Find}([k_1,k_2])  $$
implemented as Pari/GP-function (Pseudocode)

```
  Find(K) = my(z=1+I,k_1=K[1],k_2=K[2]);    \\ K is the vector [k_1,k_2]
     for(t=1,5,       \\ 5 or even only 3 iterations suffice to start Newton
           z=lb(z,k_1);
           z=lb(z,k_2);
         );
     return(Newton(z)) ;
```

***Update*** A better routine, which also employs the Newton-iteration on the branched iterated logarithm (instead on iterated exponentiation):

```
 \\Pari/GP
 default(realprecision,200) \\ my usual numerical precision
 pi2i=2*Pi*I                \\ constant
 {Find(K,maxerr=1e-100,maxit=25,z0=1+I)=my(err,L,z,l_prod,n=#K);
    L=vector(n); \\ shall contain the sequence of logarithms/periodic points

    \\ the following preconditioning is likely not needed at all
    L[1]=z0; for(it=1,3,for(i=1,n,L[(i % n) + 1]=lb(L[i],K[i])));
    z0=L[1];

    \\ Newton-iteration on branched iterated logarithm,initial value z0
    for(it=1,maxit,
      z=z0;
      L[1] = l_prod = z;
      for(i=1,n,  L[(i % n)+1]=z=log(z)+K[i]*pi2i;  if(i<n,l_prod*=z) );
      err = (z-z0)/(1/l_prod-1); \\ denominator contains derivative
      z0 -= err;
      if(abs(err) < maxerr,break());
      );
    return(L);}
```

***end update***

Using $Find([k_1,k_2])$ for $k_1=-3..3$ and $k_2=0..12$ I get the following chart of $1$- and $2$-periodic points *(they are $1$-periodic when $k_1=k_2$)* where the first parameter $k_1$ controls the color:
[image: picture]
To see the $2$-periodicities, below is the same picture whith the pairs of periodic points connected by straight lines:
[image: picture]

It is worth to note, that $2$-periodic points of the form $\text{Find}([k,-k])$ give pairs of complex conjugate numbers (big red diamonds), while $\text{Find}([k,k]) (=\text{Find}([k]))$ give $1$-periodic points (big brown circles). Note moreover that the $1$-periodic and the conjugate $2$-periodic points lay asymptotically on an (exponential) curve which can be seen, when the scale of the imaginary axis is taken as logarithmic (or even better transformed to $\sinh^{-1}()$ to see also the numbers with negative imaginary component ).

### 3-,4-,5-,... n-periodic points

If we extend the $\text{Find}([...])$ function to $3,4,5,...n$ entries $\in \mathbb Z$ in the vector-argument we find easily any $n$-periodic point which we like. $\text{Find}([0,0,1])$,$\text{Find}([0,0,-1])$,$\text{Find}([0,0,2])$,...$\text{Find}([0,1,1])$ ...

Finally $\text{Find}([k_1,k_2,k_3])$ with $k_1,k_2,k_3 \in \mathbb Z$ give ***all*** $3$-periodic points, and in case $k_1=k_2=k_3$ the $1$-periodic fixed points and in case $k_1=k_2=k_3=0$ the primary fixed point of the $\log()$-function. Unfortunately, as Y. Galidakis pointed out in his answer, the Newton-iteration for higher iterates of the $\exp()$ gets more&more involved; numerical checks up to $n=63$ and $20$ iterations in the $\text{Find}([...])$-function however looked very promising but are still under consideration.

See here some picture for examples for $n=3$,$n=5$,$n=11$,$n=31$ - periodic points.

- $3$-periodic examples

[image: picture3]
Here the coloring is chosen to make the exemplars of one shape-family better discernible where one shape-family is meant as having chosen $k_1,k_2$ constant and only $k_3$ varying.

- $5$-periodic examples

[image: picture5]

- $13$-periodic examples

[image: picture13]
I have shown only one exemplar because the overlay of more exemplars of the shape-family makes the picture too chaotic

- $31$ - periodic example

Here I show 4 exemplars of a very special shape-family by keeping all but one of the vectorial arguments to zero:
$$\text{Find}([0,0,...,0,k_{31}])$$ 
which produces the natural iteration-map for the $\log()$ for $30$ steps and then in one step adds $k_{31} \cdot C$ .
Of course, this typical shape-family exists analoguously for all $n$-periodic points.
[image: picture31]

### Remark

This scheme, ***if it is really exhausting*** (what seems obvious to me), gives nice intuition in more general statements about the nature of the set-of-periodic points of the exponential function.

- The number of $2$-periodic fixpoints is then that of $\mathbb Z^2$. All of them can be indexed like the rational numbers by a pair of *2* integer indexes.
- The number of $n$-periodic fixpoints is then that of $\mathbb Z^n$. Indexing as before, but with $n$-tuple of integer indexes.
- If I understand the topological concept of "dense subset" correctly it is immediately obvious, that the set of $n$-periodic points is "dense" (Shen/Rempe-Gillen give a reference to a proof)
- Because there is so far no reason to assume that some class of $n$-periodic points might be missing/impossible, this answers one doubt in Galidakis' answer, by here ***claiming*** that $n$-periodic point for all $n$ exist and there are $\mathbb Z^n$ of them.*(See also Shen/Rempe-Gillen, Theorem 1.1)*
- I don't know yet, whether it shall be possible to find, for instance for the $2$-periodic points, a simpler analytical description than this of the iterated branched logarithms, for instance by a parametrical definition of the curves on which that points lay, for instance to prove the exhaustiveness of my method for the set of 2-periodic orbits/points.

*Shen, Zhaiming; Rempe-Gillen, Lasse*, [**The exponential map is chaotic: an invitation to transcendental dynamics**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.10.919), Am. Math. Mon. 122, No. 10, 919-940 (2015). [ZBL1361.37002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1361.37002).

***Update:*** an article which deals with the question of $p_1$ (fixed-) points on the braches of the $\log()$-function is by Stanislav Sykora (2016) at his web-space [here](http://ebyte.it/library/docs/math16/FixedPointsExp.html) . Don't know really whether the exposition can be used at least as proof for the questions whether the set of fixed points $p_1$ found by this method here is really exhaustive, though.

Answer (score 4):

The structure of the periodic points of the exponential map is well-understood. Observe that the real axis is invariant and contains no periodic points; its preimages contain the horizontal lines at imaginary parts that are integer multiplies of $\pi$.

Consider the strips
$$ S_k := \{ a + ib\colon (2k-1)\pi < b < (2k+1)\pi\}.$$

Every periodic point $z$ has an "itinerary" $(k_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$, defined by
$$ f^n(z) \in S_{k_n}.$$
(Here $f$ is the exponential map and $f^n$ its $n$-th iterate.)

Clearly the itinerary is a periodic sequence whose period divides the period of $z$.

It is known that every periodic sequence is realised by a periodic point. When $(k_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is not the sequence $k_n \equiv 0$ for all $n$, this periodic point is unique and, in particular, has the same period as $(k_n)$.

For the sequence defined by $k_n\equiv 0$, there are two fixed points, one in the upper half-plane and one in the lower half-plane, which are complex conjugates of each other.

The periodic point for a given itinerary can be obtained by backwards iteration, as you mention. That is, let $L_k\colon \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]\to S_k$ denote the inverse of the map $f|_{S_k}$. If $z\notin\mathbb{R}$, then define
$$ z_m := L_{k_0}(L_{k_1}(\dots(L_{k_m})\dots)).$$

Then the sequence $z_m$ will converge to a periodic point with the desired itinerary, and this point is unique, except for the exceptional case $k_n\equiv 0$, where it depends on whether $\operatorname{Im} z$ is positive or negative.

It is also known that every periodic point as above, except for the case $k_n\equiv 0$ has a periodic curve to $\infty$ attached to it, periodic of the same period. This curve is called a "Devaney hair" or "external ray", and all points except the periodic endpoint converge to infinity under iteration.

I think that all of this can already be found in the paper by Devaney and Krych (Dynamics of $\exp(z)$, ETDS, 1984). They use a somewhat different convention for itineraries, but the results are equivalent.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much. I think I've seen that Devaney & Krych - paper, but didn't get the catch about the "hairs". I'll reread it soon. Meanwhile I looked at the analogue problem with other bases for exponentiation and found some irregularities awaiting to be catalogued and to be explained...

Comment: Hmm, I had two different papers of Devaney, not this one, but had come across the term "hair" already but without getting a clue, how to understand this. I think it's better to ask about this in another question here in MSE... At least I take it, that the sequences _S_ are equivalent to my concept of vector *K* of branchindexes, so this seems to answer one of my questions about my central hypothese. So thanks again for the reference!

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The structure of periodic points is quite well understood across the complex exponential family z\mapsto e^z + a (or, up to a change of variable, z\mapsto \lambda e^z, z\mapsto e^{\lambda z} etc). I suppose that this is what you mean by "other bases of exponentiation".

Comment: According to "other bases", just to take $z \to b^z$ (or $z \to \exp(\lambda z)$ ) . I've done some heuristics already and found that the vectorial adress/"index" for the periodic points has exceptions and irregularities (although likely only few ones) for that other bases $b$. From this my first/primary concern was, whether for base $b=e$ ($z \to \exp(z)$) the adressing/"indexing" was "regular"/without exceptions.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms yes, the structure is generally quite well understood in the family of general exponential maps. You have to be a little bit careful about how to define the "address" of a periodic point, since the partition by imaginary parts is no longer dynamically meaningful. Quite a lot of information about the combinatorial structure of exponential parameter space, and how it pertains to the development of periodic orbits, is in my paper with Dierk Schleicher, "Combinatorics of bifurcations in exponential parameter space".

Comment: thank you very much for your comment and the reference to your article with D. Schleicher! I thought I'd read it already, but seemingly missed it (although  mention of D.Schleicher is a trigger since long :-) ) Well, things became too tricky in August: the idea of ***fractional iteration*** should allow to plot a closed curve connecting the 3 periodic points. Having two suitable such sets, their curves would cross each other. The crossing points $p_k$ are now of interest: the same point has now fractional iterates $\exp_b^{\circ h}(p_k)$ in at least two directions (... contd...)

Comment: (...contd...) while of course any formula for fractional iteration has no "direction" argument with it. My pictures of overlapped 2-,3- or more m-periodic points indicate, that this problem should occur everywhere in the area where periodic points exist. Can we still assume existence of meaningful fractional iteration? I had no answer/idea to this from August on and had put the whole problem area at temporary suspend: the question of fractional iteration of the $\exp()$-function ("*tetration*") has been my main question over the last years, and I need an answer/a way to go there first.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I am not sure that there is a general "meaningful" fractional iteration, at least from a complex dynamics point of view - even for the standard exponential map (Kneser's real-analytic solution notwithstanding).

Comment: Dear Professor Rempe - I've continued my consideration of the periodic points to the question of fractional iteration and whether it is possible to build a continuous trajectory which is as well periodic. I seem to have arrived at a contradiction which rises doubts on the fractional iteration in this cases generally. Would you mind to kindly have a look at my current question in mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391772/ whether there is something to critizise or to backup my observation/interpretation/conclusion?

Answer (score 3):

As you may remember, you need to solve in general the $p$-th auxilliary exponential equation to find the fixed points first. The first auxilliary is $f(z)=z$, with $f=exp$. This is solved by using Lambert's $W$ function as $z_k=-W_k(-1)$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. None of these is stable as $|f'(z_k)|>1$. The second auxilliary is $f^{(2)}(z)=z$ or $e^{e^z}=z$. This cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions, so you need to use Newton's method. Once you find a solution $z_0$, the fixed points will be $z_0$ and $f(z_0)$. You can test then for the period, by using the modulus of the derivative of the multiplier, as given by Shell, as $|(f^{(2)})'(z_0)|$. If that's less than one, then it will be a 2-cycle, with limits $z_0$ and $f(z_0)$.

In general you'll have to solve the $p$-th auxiliary $f^{(p)}(z)=z$, for which you can still use Newton's method, but as the composition becomes more and more entangled, it will progressively be slower and may even fail. If you get a point $z_0$, then all $\{z_0,f(z_0),f^{(2)}(z_0),\ldots,f^{(p-1)}(z_0)\}$ will be fixed points, which you can check using again the modulus of the multipler $|(f^{(p)})'(z_0)|$.

With that said, it's unknown really whether there are points of period $p$ for arbitrary $p$ in both tetration of the exponential and/or regular tetration. You can only check individual values. In one of my papers I extract the fixed points using functions which generalize $W$, but the check is still the same. They all have to go through Shell's multiplier to check for the modulus. You can get a rough idea on where to look, by graphing the iterates of the exponential like [this](https://ingalidakis.com/math/expFractal.html).

Comment: Hi Yiannis - nice to hear from you! And thanks for the answer. Yes, I noticed that problem, that the Newton-iteration is very sensitive here for the initial approximation to some true periodicd point; that's why I implemented this "lasso"-like zooming iteration to the neighborhood of some initial (manually screened) value $z$ with good (=small) error when $ | e^{e^z}}-z| $ is applied. When I found some value with three times zoomed in, that means a local minimum in steps of $1/1000$ then this was in the area $z=1+1i$ to $z=10+10î$ always sufficient and I could automatize zoom&Newton (...)

Comment: (...) for local-minima of $z_0 \pm 1 \pm î$ in steps of $1/10$ to arrive to quadratic approximation-rate for all tested values. This gave the first data for the initial picture, nearly linear trends in neighboured $2$-periodic points allowed even to dismiss the manual screening/zooming for the extrapolation-cases. But I've seem to have just  found a break-through and a maximal lovely method to implement for automatic searching - I'll start composing an own answer later this evening. I'll be extremly curious about your opinion!

Comment: Hi Gottfried. I think the problem with Newton's method is that nasty $f'(x)$ in the denominator. The hint being that if periodicity fails on the first auxiliary, chances are it will fail in the derivative of higher iterates. In my article I avoid the problem of picking the first value for Newton's method by solving an $n$-th degree poly gotten from the exponential series. Then I apply Newton and usually get good results. If you have no surefire way of picking the first value, then Newton may not be the best choice. I would look at Halley's method instead for better results.

Comment: Hi Yiannis - please see my new answer with the explanation of my current finding.

Comment: It looks good, just some minor points: Giving a procedure for finding $p$-periodics is not a proof that such points exist for all $p>0$. This needs to be redone in the form of a proof, which can save you from a lot of pain afterwards. Second, as in the references you gave, the $\exp$ map is indeed chaotic, so this means that you can't always tell whether a point is $p$-periodic by manual inspection. Manual inspection is only good enough as a hint, but it is unreliable if the values are too close to zero (as with one of your examples). I still think that the best test is Shell's multiplier.

Comment: Also, the fact that you can index your periodics using $\mathbb{Z}$ is not indicative of such points' exhaustion. There could well be others which are not reached for any integer index. Even in the case of $p=1$, where the fixed points are given by $W$, it doesn't mean that's all of them ($-W_k(-1)$). That $\exp$ is "chaotic" means exactly that: That you cannot always determine the periods in full, due to the weird behavior of the convergent. It might LOOK like it's periodic, but in reality it can sling-shoot between infinity and zero and you can't get anything more specific.

Comment: Yes, Yiannis, the repulsive character of the (iterated) exp at the fixed- and periodic point is the problem at the core, and -I think- as you say the cause for the chaotic property of the iteration. However the idea that I introduced: to use the logarithms instead make an attracting characteristic from the repelling one. The idea of getting a bijectivity between exp() and log() by the fixed tuples of branch-coordinates may solve the problem: we know that we can approximate to arbitrary precision if we reverse the exp()-iteration into the lb(,branch)-iteration. Might you kindly reconsider this?

Comment: Sure. I have no problem with considering the iterates of $\log$ instead. The problem I point out is that whatever method you use, may not be exhaustive, by the nature of the $\exp$ map. What I am saying, is that the points you find may be good, but they may be not ALL of the periodic points for specific $p$. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes, that's clearer for me. I was also pondering this, but I did not get any idea so far, how any periodic point could exist without being trapped by the process. So I laid this idea aside for later consideration. I've no fluent experience with proving in that matter, fo instance I wouldn't know, at the moment, how to prove, that $\log()$ when the principal branch is used, has only one fixed point. Sure, that argument of yours must be answered. Thanks for insisting on it!

Comment: Upps, at the previous comment I should of course say: one fixpoint in the positive imaginary halfplane; the conjugate value is of course a fixpoint in the same way; I only didn't mention this because of sloppyness... In the same way in my answer I should remark that everything is meant to be valid for the complex conjugate values as well.

Comment: Hi, Yiannis - just for information: I've asked in MO about ideas, how to prove exhaustivity, after I had no promising idea for an approach myself - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361136 . Btw, MSE is not for discussion of proposals, but I'm looking at the idea of non-periodic "threads"(?) (based on infinite, nonperiodic vectors $K$ for $\text{Find}(K)$ with bounded coefficients, by expanding partial vectors). The found truncated orbits may be good illustration for that idea at all (in the Rempe-Gillen article)... but don't know how to proceed here...

Comment: Hi Yiannis - it seems I have an alternative to that problem of the Newton-iteration, as you state *"Then I apply Newton and usually get good results. If you have no surefire way of picking the first value, then Newton may not be the best choice."* I now tried the Newton-algo not for the iterated $\exp()$, but for the branched iterated $\log()$, and it seems it is very stable -does not need preparation of the initial value- and finds immediately the periodic points (at least that periodic points which I can index by my vectorial notation)

Answer (score 1):

***At question 2 and 3:***

I didn't find any 2-periodic points where (at least) one has negative sign on the real part.

It seems that the few cases with negative real parts are not helpful/powerful enough to base a Cesaro-summation of the infinite series on the n-periods of the periodic points.

---

The following are periods found by random-generating vectors of $K$ (values $-10...10$, periods as documented. For each period length 2000 tries. Nothing systematic so far!

```
 period:5
 [0, 0, -5, 6, 0]
 3.59082749599 + 1.47618971232*I
 1.35645844221 + 0.390038693480*I
 0.344597110913 + 0.279988561156*I
 -0.811918635625 - 30.7336040230*I
 3.42570548172 + 36.1019037153*I


 period:5
 [0, -3, 7, 0, 0]
 1.39589550907 + 0.381166300943*I
 0.369493169111 + 0.266563764150*I
 -0.786115761464 - 18.2245911795*I
 2.90370129081 + 42.3683926548*I
 3.74874562619 + 1.50236871704*I
```

6

```
 period:6
 [0, 0, 5, 0, -2, 0]
 2.50151898932 - 1.46197427832*I
 1.06381612289 - 0.528895733527*I
 0.172303614637 - 0.461379744497*I
 -0.708253491774 + 30.2025438493*I
 3.40820103291 + 1.59424215683*I
 1.32512022296 - 12.1288407143*I


 period:6
 [-10, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 -0.865726055159 - 1.16777496158*I
 0.374096952332 - 65.0405893212*I
 4.17502806712 - 14.1314152585*I
 2.69024296013 - 1.28352546925*I
 1.09217349774 - 0.445163548252*I
 0.165016321238 - 0.387035882053*I


 period:6
 [6, 0, 0, 0, 1, -5]
 1.94758289292 - 29.7291698287*I
 3.39426995654 + 36.1937328801*I
 3.59326415488 + 1.47728921312*I
 1.35714636151 + 0.390061973605*I
 0.345069979151 + 0.279869780194*I
 -0.811260602392 + 6.96462918257*I
```

7

```
 period:7
 [-3, -4, 9, 0, 0, 0, -1]
 -0.750444308081 - 5.74329299488*I
 1.75649728498 - 20.5502806192*I
 3.02651414772 - 26.6182716405*I
 3.28802037436 + 55.0910858620*I
 4.01076580829 + 1.51118369513*I
 1.45535723212 + 0.360331909844*I
 0.404999059491 + 0.242709153027*I


 period:7
 [-8, 5, -7, 1, 0, 0, 6]
 -0.170370792911 + 38.2832303265*I
 3.64502185218 - 48.6902358879*I
 3.88827281086 + 29.9198522843*I
 3.40689602021 - 42.5407328375*I
 3.75365864051 + 4.79230392555*I
 1.80621689648 + 0.906341375286*I
 0.703523044147 + 0.465078494459*I
```

8

```
 period:8
 [9, 2, 6, -10, 1, 0, 0, 4]
 -0.183435398095 + 25.6847041258*I
 3.24592114662 + 58.1266057847*I
 4.06418024304 + 14.0813826162*I
 2.68486042576 + 38.9889234027*I
 3.66564298323 - 61.3298103386*I
 4.11804903195 + 4.77208731106*I
 1.84106769616 + 0.858834846465*I
 0.708790828907 + 0.436479925461*I


 period:8
 [0, 6, 2, 8, 3, -2, 0, 0]
 1.02121461182 - 0.489741421848*I
 0.124493728473 - 0.447168470622*I
 -0.767493877253 + 36.3998441297*I
 3.59478673353 + 14.1582489042*I
 2.68153380067 + 51.5876324277*I
 3.94463110922 + 20.3684188203*I
 3.03239537454 - 11.1868702610*I
 2.45019248787 - 1.30608992453*I


 period:8
 [7, 4, 4, -4, 1, 0, 0, 2]
 -0.139550493338 + 13.1980686114*I
 2.58012639847 + 45.5636666372*I
 3.82071134899 + 26.6469711272*I
 3.29285053446 + 26.5611256149*I
 3.28707484580 - 23.6852881281*I
 3.17439265913 + 4.85028944014*I
 1.75729393145 + 0.991281741545*I
 0.701910122418 + 0.513600707428*I
```

10

```
 period:10
 [13, 11, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, 7, -8, -6]
 3.88980667763 - 39.1931011362*I
 3.67340164853 + 80.2095359456*I
 4.38569002022 + 70.6400691168*I
 4.25952110464 + 1.50879089393*I
 1.50825667185 + 0.340425849316*I
 0.435798949967 + 0.221988383926*I
 -0.715228532737 - 5.81205985617*I
 1.76745009101 - 14.2596107258*I
 2.66505425965 + 42.5348198592*I
 3.75228206472 - 48.7572601585*I


 period:10     range for entries of K is -20 to +20
 [13, 0, 0, 0, 9, -14, -4, 7, -2, -5]
 2.45890496064 - 32.6598313838*I
 3.48897209063 + 80.1857592496*I
 4.38529164743 + 1.52731263559*I
 1.53550026359 + 0.335142367490*I
 0.452125566132 + 0.214892564673*I
 -0.691955916993 + 56.9923559438*I
 4.04299085160 - 86.3816573645*I
 4.45986945473 - 26.6567678748*I
 3.29684662012 + 42.5772726672*I
 3.75430951723 - 11.0728521642*I
```

31

```
 period:31    range for entries of K is -50 to +50
 [18, 41, 5, 3, -43, -44, 35, 7, -2, 46, 32, -39, 22, 0, -49, 7, 44, 19, 17, -36, 0, 0, 0, -10, -6, 32, 12, 33, -43, 14, -43]
 4.46123659082 - 268.670811286*I
 5.59362472174 + 111.543142519*I
 4.71566725871 + 259.131288260*I
 5.55750039366 + 32.9685268863*I
 3.50956315667 + 20.2533523759*I
 3.02311284853 - 268.777751156*I
 5.59394808482 - 278.019702686*I
 5.62789436426 + 218.360807399*I
 5.38648079756 + 45.5273258094*I
 3.82526317868 - 11.1133399676*I
 2.46413008062 + 287.787230418*I
 5.66225807926 + 202.624164033*I
 5.31174315327 - 243.501368016*I
 5.49536042974 + 136.681090990*I
 4.91845800632 + 1.53061225907*I
 1.63921352217 - 307.574382164*I
 5.72873115272 + 42.4168302595*I
 3.75658336920 + 277.896704179*I
 5.62734083557 + 120.937800074*I
 4.79635775505 + 108.338449219*I
 4.68623916110 - 224.668117822*I
 5.41484177250 - 1.54994085447*I
 1.72851827511 - 0.278785039562*I
 0.560104777428 - 0.159908482226*I
 -0.540452863018 - 63.1099522429*I
 4.14491514575 - 39.2784716315*I
 3.67621370882 + 199.596270778*I
 5.29646626740 + 76.9506038467*I
 4.34552685950 + 208.847190418*I
 5.34181926132 - 268.626976088*I
 5.59352139149 + 86.4136809929*I
```

The values for the elements of the periods can be approximated to arbitrary precision, when Newton-iteration on the iterated branched logarithm is applied.